# Como pegar todos os valores HREF e SRC de um código

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala ae pessoal,

Preciso pegar todos os valores href e src das tags, link, a, img e script, para isso desenvolvi o seguinte código:

```
<html>
```

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function() {

        function execute(){

            var conteudo = $('#insert').val();

            $('#processado').html(conteudo);

            var links = $('#processado a[href],#processado link[href],#processado script[src],#processado img[data-src]'); 
            $.each(links, function(index, item){
                var caminho =  $(item).attr('href') || $(item).attr('src') || $(item).attr('data-src') || 'Nothing';
                caminho = $(item).prop('tagName') + ":" + caminho;
                $.parseHTML($('#result').append(caminho + "<br>"));
            }); 
         }

        $('#execute').click(function(){
            execute();
        });
    });            


</script>
```

```
<textarea id="insert" style="width:600px; height:80%;"></textarea>
<input id="execute" name="execute" type="submit" value="Execute">

<div id="processado" class="teste" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="result"><b>RESULTADO:</b><br>
</div>
```

O javascript funciona perfeitamente, porém, qdo copio um código fonte pra dentro do text-area e rodo o script, nada acontece.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Desde já, muito orbigado.

Comment: Que caminho complicado, hein. Não é mais fácil setar tudo num `data-src` em todos e depois filtrar por eles?

Answer (score 2):

Aqui fica uma outra sugestão:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function execute() {
    var conteudo = $('#insert').val();
        var buffer = $('<div/>');

    buffer.html(conteudo);
        var urls = $('[href], [src]', buffer).map(function(index, item) {
      return this.href || this.src;
    }).get();
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(urls));
  }
  $('#execute').click(execute);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2o1Lcz0/

Uso uma div temporária `buffer` importo o conteúdo da textarea. Depois procuro dentro dessa div elementos que tenham atributo `src` ou `href`. Depois usando `.map` converto essa array de elemento numa array com os seus valores, ou seja, o seu `href` e/ou `src`. Uso o `.get()` para converter de objeto/array jQuery numa array nativa.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Fiz uma alteração no seu código.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function execute(){

        var conteudo = $('#insert').val();

        $('#processado').html(conteudo);

        var links = $('#hideOutput').find('a[href],link[href], script[src],img[data-src]'); 

        $.each(links, function(index, item){
            var caminho =  $(item).attr('href') || $(item).attr('src') || $(item).attr('data-src') || 'Nothing';
            caminho = $(item).prop('tagName') + ":" + caminho;
            $.parseHTML($('#result').append(caminho + "<br>"));
        }); 
     }

    $('#execute').click(function(){
        execute();
    });
    });
```

E no html

```
<textarea id="insert" style="width:600px; height:80%;"></textarea>
<input id="execute" name="execute" type="submit" value="Execute">

<div id="processado" class="teste" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="result"><b>RESULTADO:</b><br>
</div>
```

A alteração consiste em jogar o conteúdo do textarea em uma div escondida, ai sim utilizar os selectors para manter o .each, caso contrario você terá que tratar a string e isso vai ficar muito mais complexo.

[Exemplo jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/pLbxu3oz/)

Veja se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução usando apenas JavaScript:

```js
var rawHTML = document.getElementById("rawHTML");
var btGetLinks = document.getElementById("btGetLinks");
var listLinks = document.getElementById("listLinks");

btGetLinks.addEventListener("click", function () {
  listLinks.innerHTML = "";
  var template = document.createElement("template");
  template.innerHTML = rawHTML.value;

  var elements = template.content.querySelectorAll("[src], [href], [data-src]");      
  [].forEach.call(elements, function (element, indice) {    
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    var value = element.src || element.href || element.dataset.src || "";
    item.textContent = element.tagName + ": " + value;
    listLinks.appendChild(item);
  });
});
```

```css
input, textarea, div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rawHTML {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="rawHTML"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="btGetLinks" type="button" value="Pegar Links" />
</div>
<div>
  <ul id="listLinks">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Uma pequena nota, ao invés de atribuir o seu HTML arbitrário a sua DIV temporária, apenas crie um fragmento com o HTML.

Outro ponto, o `a[href]`, `link[href]` e `script[src]` devem apontar para uma URL valida (não necessariamente existente).

Comment: poderia apontar o motivo do `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

valeu pela ajuda, mas acabei de executar meu código original e funcionou. O que estava dando problema é que no código q eu estava tentando rodar havia a seguinte linha de código no final.

```
    <script>
        ssiInit();
    </script>
```

Depois que removi essa parte, a o meu script funcionou corretamente e me trouxe tudo que eu precisava.

A dúvida que fica agora é, pq isso barrou a execução do meu script?

Abraços e valeu pela ajuda de todos !!!

Comment: Essa função existia no seu código? Se não, acredito que foi gerado um erro (por tentar executar uma função inexistente) e isso "travou" a execução de outros scripts. Se sim, o que ela fazia?

Comment: Essa função existia no código que eu tava lendo com o meu script....

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a maneira mais simples para fazer isso, é pegando todo o HTML diretamente no post e enviar para o processo de busca do atributo, veja como resolvi o problema:

#### HTML

```
<h2>
  Cole o HTML:
</h2>
<textarea id="insert" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></textarea><br>
  <input type="button"  onclick="executeScript()" value="Executar">

<div id="processado" class="teste" style="display:none;">
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
 function executeScript() {
     var content = '<div>' + $('#insert').val() + '</div>';
     var data = '';
     $(content).find('[href],[src],[data-src]')
           .each(function (index, value) {
             data += ((value.src != undefined) ? value.src : (value.href != undefined) ?  value.href : (value.dataset.src != undefined) ? value.dataset.src : null !== null) +"<br>";
           });
           if ( data.indexOf('<br>') == -1 ) {
                 data = 'Não há links para serem processados!';
           }
           $('#result').html('<h3>RESULTADO:</h3>' + data);
 }
```

## Aqui tem o exemplo em funcionamento